# How to link html files together using Django 1.9?

Tags: python, html, django, atom-editor

I am currently programming in the atom code editor and python 3.4.0 as well as Django 1.9. I am new to django coding.

[image: This is the tree view for where all my html file and css files are.]

I have managed to link the html files and the css files, but I don't know how to link the html files together.

I have tried the `<a href=" ">` code because normally that works (I have previous knowledge in HTML) however, everytime I click on the link, it says webpage not found.

I am trying to link base.html file to the generalq.html file.

Does anyone know any tips?

Comment: Start with the official tutorial... your question is too broad for SO

Comment: What does "link the html files together" mean? What code have you tried? What error do you get?

Comment: on the webpage i want the user to press a link and then get transferred to another webpage ( another html file). I have tried the <a href=" "> code however it doesn't work.

Comment: So what have you put in your views and urls to make the "other webpage" work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put an URL in the `href` of your `<a>` element that is handled by your `urls.py` and `views.py` files:

In `blog/templates/blog/base.html`:

```
<a href="/blog/general/">My link</a>
```

In `compproject/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

In `blog/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^general/$', views.general, name='general'),
]
```

In `blog/views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def general(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/generalq.html', {})
```

Comment: what's 'general' referring to?

Comment: I just edited my answer, 'general' is the name of the view I assumed in my example.